# Flutter Button Pagination GridView Builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I used *gridview.builder*, and I want to load five items every time a button is pressed. I tried and don't understand how to do it.

When all buttons are pressed, every time it shows more than five products. When the list didn't have more categories, all buttons disappeared.

[Design example exactly what to want I do. Please click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQez3.png)

```
class WidgetTest extends StatefulWidget {
  WidgetTest({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  // final String title;

  @override
  State<WidgetTest> createState() => _WidgetTestState();
}

class _WidgetTestState extends State<WidgetTest> {
  int present = 0;
  int perPage = 5;

  final originalItems = categoryData;

  var items = <String>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
   setState(() {
     present = present+perPage;

   });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            gridDelegate:
                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.network(
             "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ebuy-1ac5b.appspot.com/o/pngegg%201.png?alt=media&token=fb4dd43b-c537-4471-b81b-e325724f0919",
            height:30,
            width: 90,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Text("Man",
          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
          style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
  )),
        ],
      ),
    );;
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a state for list of items, and you can manipulate the state for increasing the size of list and so that the size of the grid will increase automatically.

Below is the example for the mentioned requirement:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WidgetTest extends StatefulWidget {
  WidgetTest({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  // final String title;

  @override
  State<WidgetTest> createState() => _WidgetTestState();
}

class _WidgetTestState extends State<WidgetTest> {
  int present = 0;
  int perPage = 5;

  int _count = 5;
  List<String> productList = [
    "Product 1",
    "Product 2",
    "Product 3",
    "Product 4",
    "Product 5",
    "Product 6",
    "Product 7",
    "Product 8",
    "Product 9",
    "Product 10",
    "Product 11",
    "Product 12",
    "Product 13",
    "Product 14",
    "Product 15",
    "Product 16",
    "Product 17",
    "Product 18",
    "Product 19",
    "Product 20",
    "Product 21",
  ];

  // final originalItems = categoryData;

  var items = <String>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      present = present + perPage;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: _count + 1,
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == _count) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (_count + 5 < productList.length) {
                    _count += 5;
                  } else {
                    _count += productList.length - _count;
                  }
                });
              },
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 18,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "Show More",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          return SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Image.network(
                  "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ebuy-1ac5b.appspot.com/o/pngegg%201.png?alt=media&token=fb4dd43b-c537-4471-b81b-e325724f0919",
                  height: 30,
                  width: 90,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Text(
                  productList[index],
                  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me .I am new in flutter . Please see my design . What i want is When I click  all button load more 5 product from list until the list was empty.

Comment: Does the list needs to grow or it should replace the older five items with the newer one ?

Comment: List needed to grow 5 , then 5+5, then 5+5+5

Comment: I have edited my answer please do have a look .